# Currently Active Controller/Action MVC .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In an MVC/C# application, how can I know programmatically which controller and action are executing without parsing the URL request?  Is there a way?

The goal here is that I have top-level navigation that's mainly rendered with CSS in Site.Master, and I'd like to change the style when rending the menu item that was most recently selected ... basically I'm just trying to give the user context as to where they are in the site.  Maybe i'm going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch it from the route values. For example if you are inside a custom HtmlHelper:

```
public static IHtmlString MyHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    var rd = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
    var action = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
    var controller = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to add a parameter named `action` to the controller function, the model binder will bind the action name to it.